# Excel: how to create pie chart for this multi-row/multi-column table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Imagine the following table where data is grouped in different ways. Suppose I have drinks that are either alcoholic or nonalcoholic. And then for each of these types I have 3 sub types.

For alcoholic I have beer, wine, vodka.

For nonalcoholic soda, juice, water.

In addition, I have a binary column "is clear liquid".

With Yes for water and vodka and No for everything else.

Counts for the 6 drink types add up to 100% (so, say, 5%,10%,25%,20%,20%,20% although the actual numbers are not important).

Fraction
    Clear?


    Alc
    Beer
    5%
    N


    Wine
    10%
    N


    Vodka
    25%
    Y


    Nonalc
    Juice
    20%
    N


    Water
    22%
    Y


    Soda
    18%
    N

**I need to create a single pie chart that will**

(i)  have a slice for each of the 6 types of drinks but also needs to visually 
     emphasize

(ii) all alcoholic vs all nonalcoholic

(iii) clear versus non-clear.

How would I do that in Excel?

Comment: I don't think a pie chart is the correct method for displaying all three dimensions. You might be able to show the alcoholic ones by using different shades of blue and the non-alcoholic using different shades of green.

Comment: You could color the slices with two colors for alcohol/non-alcohol. Format the slices to have outlines to distinguish slices of the same color. Add a crosshatch or other pattern for clear/non-clear.

Comment: It would be beneficial if your question actually had some mock data in table format instead of us having to type it...  **;-)**  Please [edit] your question to add such data.

Comment: @Fabby After reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites I am not sure how I would add a table